# query kdb using qpython and python3.6

Tags: python-3.6, kdb

I'm using qpython to communicate with my kdb(tickdb) server.
I have this simple script

```
q = qconnection.QConnection(host = 'host', port = 789)
q.open()
print(q)
print('IPC version: %s. Is connected: %s' % (q.protocol_version, q.is_connected()))
data = q('{`int$ til x}', 10)
```

which ends up with this exception
`qpython.qtype.QException: b'not an api call'`

Comment: Hi - which version/build/install of qpython are you running?

Comment: Are you connecting to a vanilla kdb+ instance or are there any checks being performed on messages sent via IPC? I'm asking as I have checked through the github page for qpython and can't seem to find that error string.

Comment: @terrylynch qPython==2.0.0

Comment: @SeanHehir yes, the port I was connecting to was not allowing raw queries and just some custom queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QException is a q error rather than python or qPython. As Sean has suggested it seems like you are not connecting to a vanilla kdb setup and there must be logic in the q process to block free-form user queries.

I can force the error by updating the sync message handler `.z.pg`

```
/ basic example if a symbol isn't received by the q process will return an error from the q process
q).z.pg:{if[not -11h~type x;'"not an api call"];value x}

python test2.py

:localhost:789
IPC version: 3. Is connected: True
Traceback (most recent call last):
....................................
    raise QException(self._read_symbol())
qpython.qtype.QException: b'not an api call'
```